# Use of uninitialized value $form_data{"BuildAcct"}

Tags: perl, form-data

*** SECOND UPDATE FOR SUNDAY***

Now at this point I have found some added success at displaying the desired *sub*
The new snippet of code which enabled me to actually *invoke* a specific *sub* as I wanted.

In researching I stumbled upon the following snippet which deals with reading incoming **FORM** data.
This snippet *does* enable the *invocation* of the *sub* of my choice from this script.
However from the CLI when I run **perl -x** against the script the system returns the following
*nonfatal* *warnings* that I would like to gain understanding of and resolve.
My research shows that  **(tr///)** and  **$ENV{"REQUEST_METHOD"}** and **$buffer** are returning empty
values *""* **OR** *0*.
How would I best resolve these following errors? 
I realize I can just delete any
reference to ***(tr///)*** and ***$buffer*** to resolve those errors, however, I question removing
***$ENV{"REQUEST_METHOD"}*** as it seems this imperative to the function of this snippet???

***CLI ERROR***

> ```
> Use of uninitialized value in transliteration (tr///) at test.pl line 36 (#1)
> Use of uninitialized value $ENV{"REQUEST_METHOD"} in string eq at test.pl line 37 (#1)
> Use of uninitialized value $buffer in split at test.pl line 44 (#1)
> ```

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
# (test.pl)

use DBI;
use DBD::mysql;
use warnings;
use strict;
use diagnostics;

$| = 1;

# The script I am wanting to create, is to allow users at (NAS) HotSpot to create a user account
# which is to write into MySQL db TABLE's *radcheck* and *radreply*.
#
# Now at this point I have found some added success at displaying the desired *sub*
# The new snippet of code which enabled me to actually *invoke* a specific *sub* as I wanted
# from an HTML form.
# Please see below for solution which still has some questions.

  print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

  sub BuildAcctNow {
      print "<h1 style=\"color:blue;font-family:Arial;font-size:xx-large;\">TO BUILD YOUR ACCOUNT TODAY WE WILL NEED A SMALL AMOUNT OF INFORMATION</h1><br><br>\n\n";
  }

  sub PauseAcctNow {
      print "<h2 style=\"color:red;font-family:Arial;font-size:xx-large;\">YOUR ACCOUNT HAS BEEN PAUSED PLEASE MAKE A PAYMENT HERE.</h2><br><br>\n\n";
  }

#  In researching I stumbled upon the fllowing snippet which deals with reading inward FORM data.
#  This snippet *does* enable the *invocation* of the *sub* of my choice from this script.
#  However from the CLI when I run perl -x against the script the system returns the following
#  *nonfatal* *warnings* that I would like to gain understading of and resolve.
#  My research shows that  (tr///) and  $ENV{"REQUEST_METHOD"} and $buffer are returning empty
#  values, How would I best resolve these following errors? I realize I can just delete any
#  reference to (tr///) and $buffer to resolve those errors, howerver I question removing
#  $ENV{"REQUEST_METHOD"} as it seems this imperative to the function of th ssnippet???
#
#
#  Use of uninitialized value in transliteration (tr///) at test.pl line 36 (#1)
#  Use of uninitialized value $ENV{"REQUEST_METHOD"} in string eq at test.pl line 37 (#1)
#  Use of uninitialized value $buffer in split at test.pl line 44 (#1)

    my ($buffer, @pairs, $pair, $name, $value, %FORM);

    # Read in text
    $ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} =~ tr/a-z/A-Z/;
    if ($ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} eq "POST")
    {
        read(STDIN, $buffer, $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'});
    }else {
        $buffer = $ENV{'QUERY_STRING'};
    }
    # Split information into name/value pairs
    @pairs = split(/&/, $buffer);
    foreach $pair (@pairs)
    {
        ($name, $value) = split(/=/, $pair);
        $value =~ tr/+/ /;
        $value =~ s/%(..)/pack("C", hex($1))/eg;
        $FORM{$name} = $value;
    }

  if ($FORM{PauseAcct}) {
  PauseAcctNow();
  exit;
  }

 elsif ($FORM{BuildAcct}) {
  BuildAcctNow();
  exit;
  }
```

***END SECOND SUNDAY UPDATE***

SUNDAY UPDATE **
I have made a simple script to hopefully exhibit what I am trying to do to this point hopefully?
The script I am ultimately needing to create will write to MySQL db into *radcheck* and *radreply* to enable users to log onto a (NAS) HotSpot. 
So I will have more than one subroutine within the script.

The script presently displays an empty screen VIA browser when I use a HTML doc with a properly named SUBMIT form within the doc named *BuildAcct*.

I am traditionally used to defining the *sub* within the script and then I would define *if* test(s) within the script which would wait for match(es) from any defined form name(s) when they are interacted with to then call a particular *sub*.

Below is a test script I have created just trying to get past the antiquated use of & when calling a *sub*, this is causing me some grief and I am hoping for some valuable input.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
# (test.pl)

use DBI;
use DBD::mysql;
use warnings;
#use strict;
# Presently due to my errors below I have disabled *use strict*.

$| = 1;

# The script I am wanting to create, is to allow users at (NAS) HotSpot to create a user account
# which is to write into MySQL db TABLE's *radcheck* and *radreply*.
#
# Trying to bring myself up to speed with a very basic task which I have defined below, in my
# older scripts I would define the *sub* itself, then in the script I would use an *if* test
# which checks to see if any defined FORM value returns a hit such as $form_data{'BuildAcct'} ne ""
# to call the required *sub* _ThisOne_.

  print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";

  sub ThisOne {
      print "Trying to display this subroutine upon submission of BuildAcct\n";
  }

#  Following is the *if* test I am accustomed to using to make a call to a particular sub when
#  the form NAME BuildAcct is interacted with, but this is unacceptable now I realize.
#  CLI Return:
#  Use of uninitialized value $form_data{"BuildAcct"} in string ne at test.pl line 32.
#  Use of uninitialized value $form_data{"BuildAcct"} in string ne at test.pl line 41.

  if ($form_data{'BuildAcct'} ne "")
  {
  &ThisOne;
  exit;
  }

# SO, I have Google'd, and looked over numerous methods of calling *subs*, I am just stuck though,
# Why can't the following *if* test work if use of & is no longer used?

  if ($form_data{'BuildAcct'} ne "")
  {
  ThisOne();
  exit;
  }
```

Thanking you in advance for help...
Best Regards

UPDATE **
I have turned the -w switch off on the script, not sure if that poses a negative influence, pretty new to perl.

I also created some clunky code that is ugly. 
The weird thing is that from the CLI when I execute the script the system returns:

```
Use of uninitialized value $form_data{"BuildAcct"} in string at acctmanager.pl line 211.
Use of uninitialized value $form_data{"Test"} in string at acctmanager.pl line 212.
```

Yet VIA browser from a HTML doc I can change the **SUBMIT** name value back and forth between *BuildAcct* and *Test* and the script successfully returns two different and correct subroutines when submitted.

The *BuildAcct* sub returns form fields I defined within that subroutine, whereas *Test* does a MySQL TABLE GROUP rowfetch and displays 3 different tables from a db and prints them to the browser.

Below is my present code :-(

```
local ($form_data{'BuildAcct'}) = "$form_data{'BuildAcct'}";
local ($form_data{'Test'}) = "$form_data{'Test'}";
                #
                # AddNewUser FORM definition.
if ($form_data{'BuildAcct'} ne "")
   {
   &AddNewUser;
   exit;
  }
                 #
                 # DispTest FORM definition.
elsif ($form_data{'Test'} ne "")
   {
   &DispTest;
   exit;
  }
```

Could someone give me a nudge into the right direction possibly?

Thanking you in advance

```
          ORIGINAL POST
```

At this point I have a FORM on an HTML doc named *BuildAcct*, likewise within my script I have defined the following which is to make the call to the subroutine *AddNewUser* when the user submits the HTML FORM...

```
 if ($form_data{'BuildAcct'} ne "")
   {
   &AddNewUser;
   exit;
  }
```

The script uses *cgi-lib.pl*

```
# Enable parsing of FORM_DATA VIA cgi-lib.pl.
 &ReadParse(*form_data);

## FORM or IMG FORM Fix
foreach (keys %form_data)
 {

## Fix incoming form data with Image buttons
 $form_data{$1} = $form_data{$_} if (/(.*)\.x/);
 }
```

The thing I can't understand is why does this work in another script I use but this new script returns the following upon execution at the CLI;

```
Use of uninitialized value $form_data{"BuildAcct"} in string ne at acctmanager.pl line 208.
Use of uninitialized value $form_data{"Test"} in string ne at acctmanager.pl line 215.
```

Help and suggestions are greatly appreciated.
Best Regards

Comment: Your code uses global variables, inconsistent intendation, ancient function call syntax, oh, even typeglobs. The greates WTF is the usage of the *ancient* `cgi-lib.pl`. It is utterly impossible to tell from your snippets what it does, and why you think something went wrong. On what version of perl are you? (current stable is 5.16.3!)

Comment: My perl version is: v5.14.2 I am running Ubuntu 12.04.02 LTS.  Well as I have stated I am new to perl, however, I have decided to remove cgi-lib.pl.  I will just figure this out myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that `%form_data` hash is being populated via cgi-lib.pl, therefore when you run it via command line, cgi-lib.pl isn't getting any input from the web browser... having said this, you haven't included the code where you're using cgi-lib.pl, so I can't be sure.

p.s. *don't* turn off warnings. They're there for a reason. If nothing else, you can paste the warning into google. While you're at it, alway put `use strict;` at the top of your script, and fix all undeclared variables.

Comment: Thank you Barton, very much... I will most likely be removing cgi-lib.pl. I will turn -w back on, I have got strict enabled at the top of the script. Kinda afraid after the above to even consider posting my entire script, its discouraging to ask for help and have others shred me and my lack of knowledge of perl.  Thank you very much I will take your help very happily. Best Regards

Comment: The best approach is to post the smallest piece of code which will a) run and b) demonstrates the problem. Often, the process of isolating the code will lead to your answer. Don't take critique of your code personally; by and large it's safe to assume that it isn't meant that way. If you google for my full name, you can find my twitter account; I'll be happy to show you the ropes in Perl.

Comment: Thank you very much Barton, I may just take you up on the kind offer. Last night I checked out Perl In A Nutshell; Calling Subroutines, it states: The Ampersand (&) is the identifier used to call subroutines. Most of the time however, subroutines can be used in an expression just like built-in functions. To call subroutines directly: name(args); # & is optional with parentheses / name args; # Parens optional if predeclared/imported / &name; Passes current @_ to subroutine.  I have attempted this with the call to the cgi-lib subroutine using the following: ReadParse(*form_data); FAILS
'

Answer (score 0):

To fix the error "Use of uninitialized value $form_data{"BuildAcct"} in string",

You can check with defined($form_data{"BuildAcct"})  or defined $form_data{"BuildAcct"}  like below, before making use of $form_data{"BuildAcct"} :

> if (defined $form_data{"BuildAcct"}) {   < other code based on
> $form_data{"BuildAcct"}  > }